# Appending data to .json file

Tags: node.js, json

fairly new to node and having a problem appending data to JSON file. I have a JSON file, which loads fine and data gets written to it but it seems to gets added to the end of the file causing a formatting error.

How would I load in the JSON file and append the data 'ts'? Any help appreciated.

```
var ts = {
    map_id: 4,
    time: 23456756,
    date: 'Dec342020',
    energy: 4.1
}

var fs = require ("fs");
var data = fs.readFileSync('dataNov20_daily.json');
var result = JSON.parse(data);
// result.push(ts)
console.log(result);
var data2 = JSON.stringify(ts);
fs.appendFile('dataNov20_daily.json', ',' + data2, finished)
function finished(err) {
   console.log('all set!');
}
```

Result of JSON file where data gets written to the very end causing formatting error:

```
    {
    "items": ["Data", {
        "map_id": 1,
        "time": 1606348800000,
        "date": "Nov262020",
        "energy": 29.2
    }, 
    {
        "map_id": 1,
        "time": 1606435200000,
        "date": "Nov272020",
        "energy": 26.2
    }
]
}[{"map_id":4,"time":23456756,"date":"Dec342020","energy":4.1}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming your data looks like this, correct me if I am wrong

Actual file data:

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "map_id": 4,
            "time": 1607472000000,
            "date": "Dec092020",
            "energy": 4.8
        },
        {
            "map_id": 4,
            "time": 1607558400000,
            "date": "Dec102020",
            "energy": 4.4
        }
    ]
}
```

You can over write it like this:

```
var ts = {
    map_id: 4,
    time: 23456756,
    date: 'Dec342020',
    energy: 4.1
}

var fs = require("fs");
var data = fs.readFileSync('dataNov20_daily.json');
var result = JSON.parse(data);

var uppendedData = (result && (result.items instanceof Array)) ? [...result.items, ts] : [ts];
result["items"] = uppendedData;

fs.writeFileSync('./dataNov20_daily.json', JSON.stringify(result));

function finished(err) {
    console.log('all set!');
}
```

Comment: can you update how your data looks like in the file, that way I can help you

Comment: Thanks again @kgangadhar. As in my comment above, the appended 'ts' object gets added to the very end of json file causing the end of file error. Do you see what I mean about error

Comment: Sorry, please see updated question as requested. This now contains the entire json file

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to use the result object returned by the parsing of your json file (i think it's an array right ?)
2. Push your ts object with the javascript 'push' method in the parsed result.
3. Finally, you need to use JSON.stringify and save the result object into your file with fs.writeFile

Comment: Thanks, the file is a json object. When I try to use the push method, i get an error stating that result.push is not a function,

Comment: You can read the content of the file with readFileSync function. then pass it to JSON.parse function to retrieve the JSON object stored in your file

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using the very handy [lowdb](https://github.com/typicode/lowdb) module, this gives you a huge amount of flexibility when dealing with .json files.

You can query, filter, sort, basically anything lodash lets you do.

Appending another entry to a .json file is super easy:

```
const low = require('lowdb')
const FileSync = require('lowdb/adapters/FileSync')

const dbFileName = "energy.json";
const adapter = new FileSync(dbFileName)
const db = low(adapter)

const ts = {
    map_id: 4,
    time: 23456756,
    date: 'Dec342020',
    energy: 4.1
}

// Add another entry
db.push(ts).write()

// Get all entries before 1607558400000 (example of querying)
let entries = db.filter(row => row.time < 1607558400000).value();
console.table(entries);
```

I'm assuming that energy.json looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "map_id": 4,
        "time": 1607472000000,
        "date": "Dec092020",
        "energy": 4.8
    },
    {
        "map_id": 4,
        "time": 1607558400000,
        "date": "Dec102020",
        "energy": 4.4
    }
]
```

Comment: I will need to look into additional modules in the future, thanks for sharing.

Comment: Oh yes indeed, it may be overkill for your immediate problem, but bear it in mind!